# How to send UTF-8 SMTP email?

Tags: qt, email

My code:

```
    message = "To: " + to + "\n";
    message.append("From: " + from + "\n");
    message.append("Subject: " + subject + "\n");
    message.append("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
    message.append("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=frontier\n\n");

    message.append( "--frontier\n" );
    message.append( "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n\n" );

    message.append(body);
    message.append("\n\n");
```

When I send email and using polish letters and English letters in body everything is ok - for example "ĄZKŁY". When I use only polish letters in body - for example "ĄĘĆŻŹÓŁŃŚąęćżźółńś" I get the chinese letters "ナ漂徲Ｑ尮赕繜蟪駵".

EDIT:
I get the body from QPlainTextEdit, next I execute function sendEmail where the one of the argument is body. I add the text like:

```
sendEmail( plainTextEdit->toPlainText() )
```

And the sendEmail function is:

```
void sendEmail( const QString &body )
```

And next is my previous code, which is in the sendEmail function.

EDIT 2:
When I check body value using qDebug() there is a proper text like "ĄĘĆŁÓŹŻ".

Comment: What is `body` and in what format is its contents being appended?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I add EDIT.

Comment: Have you tried using QString::toUtf8() on the body ?

Comment: Is `message` a QByteArray? Then body.toUtf8() should be the way to go.